# Retrieving TextBlock Tag Within ListBox WP

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

im trying to get the value of a textblock in a listbox when the item is selected

```
public MainPage()
    {                
        Startup.checknetwork();
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Load_List);                   
    }

    private void Load_List(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load("List.xml");
        List<XElement> elements = loadedData.Descendants("ItemTitle").ToList();
        List<RSSItem> aux = new List<RSSItem>();
        foreach (XElement rssItem in elements)
        {
            RSSItem rss = new RSSItem();               
            rss.Title1 = rssItem.Element("Title").Value;
            rss.Date1 = rssItem.Element("Uri").Value;          
            aux.Add(rss);

            TextBlock One = new TextBlock();
            One.Text = rss.Title1;
            One.Tag = rss.Date1;                 



            AListBox.Items.Add(One);         
        }
    }

    private void AList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {     
        var SelectedItem = ((TextBlock)sender).Tag as String;          
    }
```

everything loads up fine using debug.writeline it shows the correct textbox texts and tags the alist shows the list.
how ever if i select an item i just get an error

Could someone tell me what i am doing wrong
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The SelectionChanged event send by ItemsControl. So the sender is ItemsControl not a selected item. You need SelectedItem not the sender.